# AngularJS Counting objects in a folder returned by ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I am learning AngularJS and I have what I imagine is probably a simple issue.

I am using $Resource to get json objects from a folder, and need to have a count of the objects in the folder. I have been able to get the value I am looking for in a callback statement within the save function, but I am doing something wrong, and I am unable to return it to where I need to use it. I am using the count as a way to auto increment the ID's for the files created in the folder.

I have comments in the code as to where I can access the value, and where I need to access it, its all within the Save Function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My Service:

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($resource) {
var resource = $resource('/data/event/:id', {id: '@id'}, {"getAll": {method: "GET", isArray:true, params: {something: "foo"}}});
return {
    getEvent: function(eventId) {
        return resource.get({id:eventId});
    },
    save: function(event) {

        resource.query(function(data){ 
                       console.log("Event ID In: " + data.length); //value is accessible here
                      });

        event.id = ; //need to access value here
        return resource.save(event);


    },
    getAllEvents: function() {

        return resource.query();
    }
};
```

});

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like that, without the need of a wrapper around $resource

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/data/event/:id');
});
```

Then in the place you use your factory (e.g. controller code), you can define a function for this behavior

```
function saveEvent(event) {
    eventData.query(function(data){ 
        console.log("Event ID In: " + data.length); //value is accessible here
        event.id = data.length;
        eventData.save(event);
    });
}
```

But I think you should reconsider your database design. Connecting a save with a query all the time seems not like an efficient solution to me.

Comment: Thank you, I had to make some other changes for the rest of the functionality to work, but I got it in the end. This is just a tutorial I am going through, and wanted to add something extra that wasnt in it. Thanks again

Comment: @BarryThomas No problem, you're welcome. `$resource` is a really great piece of angular that can save some lines of code. Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: I'm with @Jeyp. It's my first time doing this and I kept thinking how to get like a counter id for every document. What I'm going to do:

- When open the page where's  the creation/saver form I'll make a query, then I'll know the number of documents before starting the creation/save. And do as Jeyp says: event.id = data.length;