# How to find highest id of all existing JSON elements in AngularJS using $resource

Tags: json, angularjs, service, resources

I currently am working on an online course that makes an application in AngularJS. Currently I have a directory of JSON items that looks like this

```
/..
/data
   /event //contains 1 .json file for every item I would like to check
      1.json
      2.json
      3.json
/js
   /controllers
   /services
      EventData.js
/lib //(This folder contains the AngularJS files)
```

An example of one of the JSON files looks like this:

```
{"name": "Angular Boot Camp",
            "id": 1,
            "date": "1/1/2013",
            "time": "10:30 am",
            "location": {
                "address": "Google Headquarters",
                "city": "Mountain View",
                "province": "CA"
            },
            "imageUrl": "http://pascalprecht.github.com/slides/angularjs-insights/img/angularjs-logo.png"
}
```

And currently my EventData.js file looks like this

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($resource){
    var resource = $resource('/data/event/:Id', {Id: '@id'});

    return{
        getEvent: function() {
            return resource.get({id:1});
        },
        save: function(exampleEvent){
            exampleEvent.id = 999;
            return resource.save(exampleEvent);
        },
    };
});
```

The task in the course says "Update the save function of the eventData service to lookup next exampleEvent.id by finding the highest event id of all existing events and incrementing by one (instead of just setting it to 999)."

Currently I have tried something like this

```
 save: function(exampleEvent){
            console.log(resource.query())
            exampleEvent.id = 777;
            return resource.save(exampleEvent);
        },
```

To see if I could get an array of JSON objects so I could look through them for their ids but this doesn't work. My query returns

```
http://localhost:8000/data/event/ 404 (Not Found)
```

The json files are accessible by using a url such as http://localhost:8000/data/event/1.json. But nothing comes up using localhost:8000/data/event/.
I don't know what I am doing wrong with the resource.query function, but I am also not sure if this is even the right direction to go. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: For anyone who is doing the same tutorial who finds this, the problem was in my web-server.js file. I needed to add this line app.get('/data/event', events.getAll); which references a function in the eventsController.js file in my scripts folder. The get all function gets all the json files and concatenates them into one array.

```
module.exports.getAll = function(req, res) {
    var path = 'app/data/event/';

    var files = [];
    try {
        files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.send('[]');
        res.end();
    }
    var results = "[";
    for (var idx = 0; idx < files.length; idx++) {
        if (files[idx].indexOf(".json") == files[idx].length - 5) {
            results += fs.readFileSync(path + "/" + files[idx]) + ",";
        }
    }
    results = results.substr(0, results.length - 1);
    results += "]";

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(results);
    res.end();
};
```

The rest can be done by following these directions here:
[AngularJS Counting objects in a folder returned by ngResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811367/angularjs-counting-objects-in-a-folder-returned-by-ngresource)

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is not just a typo. In your directory tree, you have `events` (plural), and everywhere else you are using `event` (singular).

Comment: It was not just a typo. I made a mistake in my question but the directory is indeed data/event. Still getting 404 with $resource.query